Visual studio Code + Python -> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '-name module-'
Started learning python + Visual Studio Code + PlayWight. I took the article as a basis for studying (https://habr.com/ru/articles/708932/). First of all, I tried to run it on Eclipse - everything worked without problems, but I want to switch to Visual Studio Code. When I run the code in VS Code I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'". I've read a lot of articles on this subject, including on stackoverflow. Not a single article could help me solve my problem. Perhaps someone encountered and solved a similar problem with exactly this project template and file location.

error:



lounch.json file:


3.settings.json file:

Tried different options using PYTHONPATH however, I didn’t overcome the error and I don’t know what else to look. I tried using the following options
   "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
   "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/mySubdir:${env:PYTHONPATH}"}

   "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/pages/"}

   "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}\\pages\\"}

   "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolderBasename}"}

How else can you solve the problem? Thank you!

We don't want pictures. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

It's *PYTHONPATH, not -PATCH (in your try via that method).
Your first option fails because for Python, pages is a module, but as stated here: a module is a file ending in .py
Your "pages" is just a directory, and that's your problem: using pages. syntax will never work. (Unless you created a module called pages.py of course...)
It should work if you omit the pages. part of your import statement.
The link also contains the information you need to make your setup work (using either method).

Thank you. ok, I made a mistake with PYTHONPATH -  however, the problem is not solved this way. If you enter these same commands in the VS Code terminal, the paths are still not added. I've read this article before, I'm probably missing something. But still, if the same project structure works in Eclipse, then why is it not possible to configure the same project structure to work in VS Code. Also, VS Code doesn't log any syntax errors.

I'm sorry, I thought that I was more clear: you should try with pages. omitted from the import statement (as per the geeksforgeeks link that I mentioned and you have already read... -> both regarding PATCH/PATH and the import statements: in programming it's very important to pay attention to the details when copying stuff or following examples)
Did the import statement containing pages. work in Eclipse?

So, the code is the same for both IDEs, only this code works in Eclipse, but does not work in VS Code. I'm also trying this method - import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"d:\Doc\Eclips_to_Vs\PlaywrTest\pages\r")
however, in VS Code everything also does not work ((

Here is a project, try it if possible. I even added init to the "pages" folder
https://fex.net/ru/s/fkc3bza

adding the following lines to the code
import sys sys.path.insert(0,"d:\\Doc\\Eclips_to_Vs\\PlaywrTest\\") print(sys.path)
helped solve the problem. However, I'm not sure that this is the best option.
